# Cannot get jQuery dataTables to fill container

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604933/jquery-datatables-table-width-problem). I would like my table to fill its container, but it takes on whatever size it wants to.

The html tags around the table are:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <section>
      <table id="my_table">
```

The css for div and section:

```
div {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0;
}

section {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

I am not doing anything fancy with dataTables:

```
$('#my_table').dataTable()
```

I tried pretty much everything in the linked post, but I cannot get the dataTables to fill their container. I removed autoWidth and set the 4 columns to be 25% each. This changed their relative sizes but the total width was still too small.

Could this have anything to do with the section tag?

When I enter anything in the search field, the table becomes the appropriate size.

A jsFiddle that replicates the problem for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/mushroom/GHU4f/1/

Comment: Do you have <thead> tags defined? Datatables requires the table have them

Comment: Yes, I have the thead tags defined.

Comment: Can you share a link to a working example of them problem in something like jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Or at least post the HTML so that the problem can be diagnosed

Comment: Added a link to jsFiddle that replicates the problem for me.  I get the behavior I described when using both firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding width : 100% to the section css fixed the issue:

```
section {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below to "table" element works for me.

```
style="width: 100%;"
```