# Adjust width and padding of data tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I have around 6 tables those padding or width is different.When I was not using data tables, their padding and width were set inline. Now the inline doesn't work.

Datatables: http://datatables.net/index

What should I do now?

I simply need to be able to add some padding and width Inline  to data-tables or may be I could give those tables a class name and then give them padding and width.

The issue is that inline styles doesn't work with data-tables.

Using this code:

```
            <table  class="datatable display " border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1"style="width: 87%;margin: -1px 0 14px 27px;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>DOB</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Sex</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Here's the result :
[image]

Its not showing up properly due to margin and width.

Comment: zzzzzzzz..... Code, please?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this? [Datatables Custom styling](http://datatables.net/styling/custom_classes)

Comment: I don't want to initialise many times to adjust their width or padding.

Comment: You can add external styles.

Comment: The only class available for changing css is dataTables_wrapper and I can not create a new one.I need different width and padding for different tables.

Comment: Are you displaying all that tables on one page?

Comment: In some cases there are two table in one page but on tab.

Comment: What technology you are using? .net?

Comment: Check this this might help u. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604933/jquery-datatables-table-width-problem?rq=1

Comment: Thats not the issue, Btw thanks for replies, I have fixed my problem.I wrapped my tables inside div with different classes and added styles relatively.

Comment: @SachinPrasad, Welcome. It's good to know that you have got the solution.