# Cannot get Datatables and Jquery Tabs to display correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables, jquery-tabs

there is a working example on the datatables website here:
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html

BUT, i believe the example is using jquery-ui 1.8 something and this example no long work for the newer versions of jquery-ui.  Specifically this code:

```
"show": function(event, ui) {
  var table = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true);
  if ( table.length > 0 ) {
    $(table).dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
  }
}
```

i believe the "show" event is deprecated:  http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-show-event-renamed-to-activate

i tried replacing "show" with "activate", but it doesn't seem to work.  Has anyone else has this problem?  i can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: If you replace "show" with "activate", the event is called correctly, eg the columns is resized, also in jQuery UI 1.10.x (latest) - also, without "activate" the tabs and table is initialized correct. what does not work? Are you sure you have jQueru UI js/css properly loaded?

Comment: I really wish they had an example where the datatables existing in multiple ajax elements instead of a single page.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example which uses `activate` and the latest versions of jQuery and jQuery UI http://jsfiddle.net/5AavQ/3/ . Check *External Resources* to see what files were included. Make sure to include all external .js (*jQuery, jQuery UI, DataTables*) and .css (*jQuery UI*, DataTables Demo is optional) files.

Comment: No, show is _explicitly_ related to jQuery UI tabs. It is correct to replace `show` with `activate`. As the jQuery-docs says, "show" is definetely removed from UI 1.10 ...

Comment: Here is a forked jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tNRwZ/ - compare with the "working" example : Without activate the columns are never resized (the event is never called)

Comment: Thanks, davidkonrad. I've removed the incorrect assumption from my answer and updated the link to jsfiddle.

Comment: hey davidkonrad , can you please tell me .. how i can show resp. tab to resp users ( i means there is 3 tab  and i want the user who login have access to his resp. tab only and other tabs should be display or inactive or not clickable )

Answer (score 1):

I just posted a working solution to this problem in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19133945/2497086). Works on multiple tables in multiple tabs. Here is the code:

```
$(function () {

// INIT TABS WITH DATATABLES
$("#TabsId").tabs({
activate: function (event, ui) {
    var oTable = $('div.dataTables_scrollBody>table:visible', ui.panel).dataTable();
    if (oTable.length > 0) {
        oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
    }
}
});

// INIT DATATABLES
// options for datatables
var optDataTables = {
"sScrollY": "200px",
"bScrollCollapse": true,
"bPaginate": false,
"bJQueryUI": true,
"aoColumnDefs": [
    { "sWidth": "10%", "aTargets": [-1] }
]
};
// initialize data table
$('table').dataTable(optDataTables);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

myTab3 is id of tab

```
  $('#myTab3 a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
            // FYP-table is id of datatable
            $('#FYP-table').dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();

        });
```