# Datatable responsive width more than parent width

Tags: jquery, datatable

Even using responsive option in jquery datatables it happens that in lower resolutions the calculated width of table is more than the parent div, so this is happening:
[image]

The table is defined like this:

```
<table id="datatableGroupsList" class="table table-striped table-bordered responsive no-wrap table-hover partialViewPanel" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

And the datatables script called like this:

```
/* Datatables responsive */
var dataTableGroupList = function () {
    var table = $('#datatableGroupsList').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        "columns": [null, null, null, { "orderable": false } //Desabilitar ordenação na coluna das acções
        ],
        language: {
            url: window.location.origin + '/Home/GetLocalizationForDataTable'
        },
        paging: true
    }).on("init", function () {
        var tt = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools(table,
            {
                "aButtons": [
                    {
                        "sExtends": "copy",
                        "sButtonText": "@Resources.ResourcesGeneral.Copy",
                        "mColumns": [0, 1, 2]
                    },
                    {
                        "sExtends": "xls",
                        "mColumns": [0, 1, 2]
                    },
                    {
                        "sExtends": "pdf",
                        "mColumns": [0, 1, 2]
                    },
                    {
                        "sExtends": "print",
                        "sButtonText": "@Resources.ResourcesGeneral.Print",
                        "mColumns": [0, 1, 2]
                    }
                ]
            }
            );
        $(tt.fnContainer()).insertBefore('#datatableGroupsList_wrapper div.dataTables_filter');
        $('.DTTT_container').addClass('btn-group');
        $('.DTTT_container a').addClass('btn btn-default btn-md');
        $('.dataTables_filter input').attr("placeholder", "@(Resources.ResourcesGeneral.Search)..."); 

    })
    ;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
         dataTableGroupList();   
});
```

Btw, this question is about the same i'm asking:
[jQuery DataTables: control table width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604933/jquery-datatables-control-table-width/1544925#1544925)
Also i'm using version 1.10.2 of datatable.js

Does anyone had this problem and/or knows the solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be this link helps you.
https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/responsive.html

Sub table in each row.

Comment: Hello, i don't see how a row reorder can help me with my problem. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

1. Define a new class, I called mine "**wrappable**". Adding this class to `datatable` column class makes it wrap text in cell so it does not overflow to other cells on the right

   `table.dataTable tbody td.wrappable { white-space:normal; }`
2. Apply class to column in your `dataTable`

   `var columns = [ { data: null, title: " Request Details ", className: "all wrappable", width: '200px', sortable: true, autoWidth: false, render: function (data, type, row) { var year = '<div>Fiscal Year: ' + naIfNullOrEmpty(data.FISCAL_YEAR) + '</div>'; var cycle = '<div>Cycle: ' + naIfNullOrEmpty(data.CdSnfCycle.NAME) + '</div>'; var notes = '<br />Notes: ' + naIfNullOrEmpty(data.NOTES) + ' '; return year + cycle + notes; } }, ]`

Hope this helps.