# DataTables.js - Table not loading initial 100% full width on page load

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am loading a PHP page with a table using DataTables fixed header functionality.  I can not seem to get the table to be at 100% of page load while page renders.  It starts off as compressed (while loading) then expanded (once page renders).

I tried to resolve this by output buffering in php but can not get the effect of compression then expansion to go away.

**Initialization Code (At Bottom of Script)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summary_table').DataTable( {
        "scrollY": 400,
        "scrollX": true,
         "bSort": false,
         "bPaginate": false,
         "autoWidth": false 
    } );

    $(".dataTables_wrapper").css("width","100%");
});
```

EDIT:

(Table is compressed during load but then goes to 100%.)

[image: Table during page load]

**PHP**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Action Item Summary</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css"/>
    <style>
        thead th {
            background-color:#0038a8;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-style: italic;
            color: white;
            text-align: left;
        }

        table:not(#header):not(#menu):not(#find) {
            background-color: white;
            width: 100%;
        }
        td {
            width: auto;
            min-width: auto;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        input[type='text'] {
            width: 50%;
            min-width: 100%;
        }

        span {
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        span.late{
            color: red;
        }
        thead tr td a{
            color: white;
        }
        th a:hover
        {
            cursor: pointer;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }   
    div.dataTables_wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    div.dataTables_scrollBody table#summary_table {
        width: 100% !important;
    }

    table.dataTable tr.odd { background-color: #dae1e9; }
    table.dataTable tr.even { background-color: white; }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/table.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<? $pageTitle="All Action Items (".count($resAll).")"; include_once('../shared/pageheader.php'); ?>
<?if (isset($_SESSION['filteron']) && $_SESSION['filteron'] == true):?><div style="position:relative; float:right; display: inline; font-weight: bold; color:red; font-size: 12pt; background-color: lightgray; margin-right: 10">  Filter On </div><br /><?endif;?>
<form method="POST" action="/actionitems/viewactionitem.php">
<table id="find" border="1">
<tr>
    <td class="label">Find Action Item</td>
    <td style="width:100 !important"><input type="text" id="id" name="id" value=""></input></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="View" /></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Find" onclick="jumpTo($('#id').val())"+/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<table style="background-color: transparent">
<tr>
    <td id="left" align="left">
        <? if($_SESSION['userrole'] == 'Admin'): ?>[<a style="text-decoration: underline; color: black" href="newactionitem.php"><b>Add New Action Item</b></a>] <? endif;?>
    </td>
    <td id="middle" align="middle">
        [<a style="text-decoration: underline; color: black" href="allactionitems.php"><b>All Action Items</b></a>] &nbsp; 
        [<a style="text-decoration: underline; color: black" href="openactionitems.php"><b>Open Action Items</b></a>] &nbsp; 
        [<a style="text-decoration: underline; color: black" href="completedactionitems.php"><b>Completed Action Items</b></a>] &nbsp; 
        [<a style="text-decoration: underline; color: black" href="closedactionitems.php"><b>Closed Action Items</b></a>]
    </td>
    <td id="right">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<form style="display:inline" id="summaryform" method="POST" action="allactionitems.php">
<div class="summary_table" style="<? if(count($resAll)>  23): ?>height:500;<?endif;?> overflow-y:auto">
<table id="summary_table" class="display nowrap"  style="width: 1000" border=1>
    <thead class="header">
        <tr>
            <? foreach ($cols as $cidx=>$col): ?>
                <? if (!in_array($col, $hideCols)): ?>
                    <th>
                    <?if (in_array($col, $categoryNames)):?>
                        <a onclick="$('#summaryform').attr('action', 'allactionitems.php?orderby=<?=$manageActionItems->getCategoryName($col)?>&dir=<?=($dir=="DESC")?"ASC":"DESC"?>'); $('#summaryform').submit();"><?=$manageActionItems->getCategoryName($col)?></a><? if ($orderBy == $manageActionItems->getCategoryName($col) && $dir == "DESC") echo "<white>&#9660;</white>"; else if ($orderBy == $manageActionItems->getCategoryName($col) && $dir == "ASC")  echo "<white>&#9650;</white>"; else echo "<span style='display: inline-block; width: 13'></span>";?></td>
                    <? else:?>
                        <a onclick="$('#summaryform').attr('action', 'allactionitems.php?orderby=<?=$col?>&dir=<?=($dir=="DESC")?"ASC":"DESC"?>'); $('#summaryform').submit();"><?=($col=="ActionItemID")?"ID": $col?></a><? if ($orderBy == $col && $dir == "DESC") echo "<white>&#9660;</white>"; else if ($orderBy == $col && $dir == "ASC")  echo "<white>&#9650;</white>"; else echo "<span style='display: inline-block; width: 13'></span>"; ?>
                    <?endif;?>
                    </th>
                <? endif; ?>
            <? endforeach; ?>
            <th>
                View
            </th>   
            <th>
                Edit
            </th>   
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <? foreach($resAll as $idx=>$row): ?>
        <? //echo"<pre>"; var_dump($row); echo"</pre>"; ?>
        <tr id="row<?=$row['ActionItemID']?>">
            <? foreach ($cols as $cidx=>$col): ?>
                <? if (!in_array($col, $hideCols)): ?> 
                            <td <? if($orderBy == $col) echo "class='sort'"; ?>>
                            &nbsp;
                    </td>
                <? endif; ?>
            <? endforeach; ?>
            <td>
                <a href="viewactionitem.php?id=<?=$row['ActionItemID']?>">View</a>
                    <!--input type="submit" value="View" style="width:60;height:20;border:none; font-weight: bold"/-->
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
            <? if(($_SESSION['userrole'] == 'Admin' && $_SESSION['userrole'] == 'Admin') || isset($_SESSION['userid']) &&($row['OwnerID'] == $_SESSION['userid'] || $row['AltOwnerID'] == $_SESSION['userid'])):?>
                <a href="editactionitem.php?id=<?=$row['ActionItemID']?>">Edit</a>
                <? endif; ?>
                    <!--input type="submit" value="Edit" style="width:60;height:20; border:none;font-weight: bold" /-->
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <? endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summary_table').DataTable( {
        "scrollY": 400,
        "scrollX": true,
         "bSort": false,
         "bPaginate": false,
         "autoWidth": false 
    } );

    $(".dataTables_wrapper").css("width","100%");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
div#splash
{
    background-color:#d8d8d8;
}

body
{
    font-family: arial;
}

textarea
{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    max-height: 85px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    resize: none;
    font-family: inherit;
}

html * :not(h1):not(h2)
{
    font-size: 10pt;
}

body
{
    margin: 0px;    
    background-image: url('/img/custom_back.gif');
}

h1, h2
{   
    font-family: arial;
    text-align: center;
}

h3
{
    font-size: 75%;
}

table.data tr td:not(.label)
{
    background-color:white;
}

td#left
{
    width: 25%;
}

td#right
{
    width: 25%;
}

td#middle
{
    width: 50%;
}

td.label
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

table#find tr td.label,
table.data tr td.label
{
    background-color:#0038a8;
    color: white;
}

table.data tr td.label,
table.data:not(#details) tr td
{
    width: 25%;
}

table.data
{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

table#header
{
    width: 100% !important;
}

table#header tr td
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: transparent;
}


input[type=submit]
{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

td
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
div#header div
{
    display:inline-block;
}

div#title
{
    font-style: italic;
}

img#logo
{
    width: 95px;
    height: 95px;
}

table#toolname td
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
}

table#menu 
{
    background-color: #0038a8;
}

.required
{
            border-style:solid;
            border-width:2px;
            border-color:red;
}

td > div:not(.filterinput):not(.cell) 
{ 
    height: 85px;
    max-height: 85px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
} 

td.sort
{
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: If needed I can post the image of the table state as the page is synchronously rendering.

Comment: Please do! (More letters.)

Comment: you really need to post the entire page code + css as the datatable should render at 100% by defaut. seems to me like 100% is not what you thought 100% would be. only way to know is to see the whole page.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe I have resolved the issue.  I was using an older build.

After upgrading to 10.1 and following the table width instruction below, I resolved my issue.

I added (width="100%") to my table tag and it now stays at 100%

So instead of

```
<table id="summary_table" class="display nowrap" style="width: 1000" border=1>
```

I replaced the style `width: 1000` which just sets the absolute width to 1000 pixels (I forgot to add the `px` unit suffix), to a percentage value of 100% `width='100%' and the resolving table tag would read.

```
<table id="summary_table" class="display nowrap" width="100%" border=1>
```

I used the answer from this question to form my response

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23842795/1691103

Example

http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/flexible_width.html

Answer (score 46):

## for Bootstrap 4 Users

If you are using Bootstrap classes to the table, you might ran into this width issue. To fix this, use the datatable default option `"autoWidth": false`

> Enable or disable automatic column width calculation. This can be
> disabled as an optimisation (it takes a finite amount of time to
> calculate the widths) if the tables widths are passed in using

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "autoWidth": false
});
```

https://datatables.net/reference/option/autoWidth

Comment: "autoWidth": false  seemed to already be present in the original code

Comment: @Vahe Yes, i noticed that but my answer works on Bootstrap 4 with no extra code. Tested too.

Comment: I noticed the Bootstrap 4 note late, thanks for the answer

Comment: @Vahe same condition like me

Comment: Not sure if its linked to bootstrap 4 cause mine is 4.4 but the problem was fixed by doing what Dexter suggested. He is a legend !

Comment: To force an automatic width adjustment, you can also just add the `.w-100` bootstrap class to your `.table` HTML Element

Comment: Had table-responsive class added to table.  Bootstrap classes caused this issue for me.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer working fine to me.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem and tried all the above solutions but no luck.
After hours of search, I found that the bootstrap class "table-responsive" has a problem with the DataTable.

So the solution is -

Just remove the "table-responsive" class from the table.

So the HTML of the table should look like this -

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm" id="followup-table">
      <thead>
           <tr class="text-white">
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Follow Up On</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone No</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>              
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>4 Jun 2021</td>
                <td>Mrityunjay Mishra</td>
                <td>87838734</td>
                </tr> 
        </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#followup-table').DataTable();
    } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I read all the answers. none of them mentioned this simple way:

just add `style="width:100%"` to the `table` tag

```
<table style="width:100%" class="table table-striped- table-bordered table-hover table-checkable" id="firstmile-tbl" >
```

Comment: This is almost similar in intent as what I originally wrote but it is successfully using explicit style definition inside the table tag.  I think it is sufficiently different than mine for an up vote since it uniquely answers the question.  Thank You!

Comment: @VaheJabagchourian of course your answer was good for `vote up` and thank you for your compliment

Answer (score 1):

For me in Bootstrap 4.4.1 unfortunately Dexters solution didn't work. The solution is to add a class of w-100 to the table.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) don't forget to add the `table` class to your table.

```html
<table id="my_table" class="table">
    ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me adding css selector to the parent div of the table worked like a charm!

```
div.dataTables_wrapper {
width:100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `Bootastrap 4` and I wanna show the responsive table in a `card`. In my case removing `table-responsive` and `row` class from the parent `div` element did the trick. Example bellow:

Initial:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <p>Responsive Table</p>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-responsive"></table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Changed to:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="">
            <p>Responsive Table</p>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover"></table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The removal of table-responsive seems to correspond with Mrityunjay's answer, however  the answer he provided does not mention removal of the row from a potential wrapper div.   Unclear if this is unique from his answer, but it seems to include that different part.   Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Exactly! Thats why I posted this as an answer as it a possible solution since it worked for me. Happy to contribute!